# Get filename from PharData Archive itself

Tags: php, filenames, phar

My class creates `PharData` archives for me. The name of the archive isn't known to all functions of the class. Basically I have an outline like this:

```
public function doStuff(\PharData $bundle)
{
    $file = //someFile
    $bundle->addFile($file);

    $this->db->update($file is in $bundle->getName(????));
}
```

The only way to get access to the bundles name as far as i can tell is the `getAlias()` function of the `$bundle` variable. However this gives me the fully qualified filename and I would need to manually `basename($bundle->getAlias())`.

I'm really wondering if there's no way in the `PharData` class to get the actual archive filename itself.

I do NOT need the name of the files inside the archive, really all I need is to get access to the filename of the archive itself. I just don't know how reliant the `getAlias()` really is since it's name is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store own data with [`PharData::setMetadata()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/phardata.setmetadata.php) method. So you can store the filename in PHARs meta data and get it again at some later point with the [`PharData::getMetadata()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/phar.getmetadata.php) method.

Set it like this:

```
$bundle->setMetaData(array('bundleFileName' => 'your_bundle.phar'));
```

So you could then get it in your method like this:

```
public function doStuff(\PharData $bundle)
{
    $metaData = $bundle->getMetaData();
    $file     = //some File

    $bundle->addFile($file);

    $this->db->update($file is in $bundle->getMetadata['bundleFileName']);
}
```

But I think if you design your class properly you don't need this ugly workaround.

Comment: Hm, i guess this works in my case at least for this information :) Thanks for this. I'll edit your answer a bit to showcase better what I'm actually doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

The question is already somewhat older, but to the supplement:

> I'm really wondering if there's no way in the PharData class to get the actual archive filename itself.

PharData extends FilesystemIterator and therefore you can use

```
// Get the path to the current DirectoryIterator item.
// DirectoryIterator::getPath();
$bundle->getPath();
```

http://php.net/manual/de/class.filesystemiterator.php